# How to use INET or Mixim's module in my own custom project

Tags: c++, omnet++

I want to build my own custom wireless sensor network project by using simple modules in INET or Mixim. How can I use them ? I try the following codes in my cc file and NED file, but the system cannot find them. So do I need to create my project under the subdirectory of INET ? Is there any other method?

```
#include "inet/common/INETDefs.h"
#include "inet/networklayer/contract/IInterfaceTable.h" 

import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.IPv4NetworkConfigurator;
import inet.node.inet.INetworkNode;
```

There is another question, how can i find the achieve C++ file of examples in INET ? Because there are only ned files in the examples without the achieve C++ fileS, I want to find out how the examples work. Any help ?

Comment: All you need to do is make sure that the relevant INET and OMNeT++ header files are in your build path. Typically you do this by creating a make file (or by configuring the build dependencies in an IDE, such as the OMNeT++ IDE). I personally prefer including things in the INET tree, though. For both, the best way to figure out how to do this is probably to familiarize yourself with the build process of INET -- that also helps for debugging your project in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make sure that the INET project is open in your workspace
- Right click your own project in the project explorer and select Properties.
- Find the Project dependencies page and select INET as a dependency

After this, both the NED packages and the header files should be available to your project.